# Awesomium: Return HTML Source Without Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, awesomium

I would like to grab the HTML source in a string without using Javascript. Does anyone know of a way to accomplish this?

My problem spurs from the motivation to grab HTML source before a Javascript gets the chance to modify the document's contents. I have turned Javascript off in my WebSession instance in order to accomplish this. However, doing so eliminates my only known ability to fetch the HTML source!

Simply delaying the JS from running in time to capture source code would also work. Is this doable?

Thanks.

Comment: where is the string? you could always store a hidden div that holds some information and then use javascript to modify the div so that it's no longer hidden

Answer (score 0):

What's the point of using Awesomium for this? Just make GET request using WebClient or HttpWebRequest.

There is [HTML property](http://docs.awesomium.net/html/P_Awesomium_Windows_Forms_WebControl_HTML.htm) since 1.7.4, you can try it.

```
string html = webControl.HTML;
```

However when I tested it few months ago it worked not in all cases. http://answers.awesomium.com/questions/4550/html-property-in-174-only-contains-head-element.html